# Is the space $C_0^{k}(\Omega)$ a Montel space?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I asked this question in the [MathStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4888421/is-the-space-c-0m-omega-a-montel-space), but I think I'm not get any answer.

I'm trying to find a reference for the following result:

**Theorem:** Let $\Omega$ be a open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $k\geq 0$. Then $C_0^{k}(\Omega)$ it is (not) a (semi-)Montel space.

I tried to find in the classical references, Trèves, Horváth, but without success. The best result I found, it is the the Exercise 34.4 in Trèves book, which ensures that $C^k(\Omega)$ it is not a Montel space. Can we conclude from this exercise the Theorem above?

I'm trying to prove the following [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4888097/langle-t-varphi-n-rangle-rightarrow-0-for-all-distribution-t-of-finite?noredirect=1#comment10427970_4888097), but I don't know if this result is valid.

A proof of this result would also be welcome.

Comment: At least for $k = \infty$ $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ is a Montel space (Bourbaki, Topological Vector Spaces IV, Example 4 on p. IV.18).

Comment: @DieterKadelka Yes, this result is also found in Trèves and Horváth's books. My question is when $0\leq k <\infty$.

Comment: Just to be sure : $C^k_0(\Omega)$ is the set of compactly (in $\Omega$) $C^k(\Omega)$ functions that you equip with the inductive limit topology for which $(\varphi_n)_n\rightarrow \varphi$ means existence of $K$ compact subset of $\Omega$ containing supports of all $\varphi_n$ and $\varphi$ function, with uniform convergence on $K$ up to the $k$-th derivative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following I write $C^k_K(\Omega)$ for the space of all $C^k(\Omega)$ functions having support included in $K$, equipped with its "natural" norm $\|\cdot\|_{K,k}$ (uniform norm on $K$ of all derivatives up to the order $k$). I also fix a countable exhaustion $(K_n)_n$ of $\Omega$. I assume that $C^k_0(\Omega)$ is equipped with the inductive limit topology $\tau$ which satisfies in particular :

$(i)$  For all $n$, the embedding $C^k_{K_n}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow C^k_0(\Omega)$ is continuous

$(ii)$ The trace topology of $\tau$ on $C^k_{K_n}(\Omega)$ is precisely the one of $\|\cdot\|_{K_n,k}$.

In this setting, I think that $C^k_0(\Omega)$ is not Montel, for finite $k$.

Indeed : $C^k_{K_n}(\Omega)$ is a normed space of infinite dimension : it cannot be Montel (this argument fails when $k=\infty$ obviously), for instance the unit ball of $C^k_{K_n}(\Omega)$ is bounded and not compact. Because of $(i)$, this unit ball is also bounded in $C^k_0(\Omega)$. But because of $(ii)$, it cannot be compact for the $\tau$ toplogy, otherwise this would imply compactness in $C^k_{K_n}(\Omega)$.

Comment: A thing missing here is the fact that $E=C^k_0(\Omega)$ is a *strict* (lc) inductive limit and therefore it induces on $E_n=C^k_{K_n}(\Omega)$ its original topology for all $n$. This is only true for strict (lc) inductive limits. Moreover, since in this case (also not generally true for all (lc) inductive limits) $E_n$ is closed in $E$ for all $n$, it follows that $E$ is a *regular* inductive limit, that is, any bounded subset of $E$ is contained and bounded in $E_n$ for some $n$. All that together implies that a compact subset of $E$ must be contained and compact in $E_n$ for some $n$.

Comment: Otherwise you cannot argue that if the unit ball of $E_n$ is compact in $E$, then it's compact in $E_n$ as well.

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro So the conclusion is that there is problem in the above proof?

Comment: Not really, with the above remarks Ayman's proof is correct. Actually, the regularity of the inductive limit is not really needed (it only shows that any bounded subset of $E$ is a bounded subset of $E_n$ for some $n$, but we know that already for the unit ball of $E_n$ since continuous linear maps send bounded sets to bounded sets), but the closedness of $E_n$ in $E$ for all $n$ *is* directly needed to guarantee that a closed subset of $E_n$ is also closed in $E$.

Comment: With these provisos in mind, what Ayman shows is that the unit ball of $E_n$ is closed and bounded in $E$ but it cannot be compact there, for otherwise it would be compact in $E_n$ as well. Hence $E$ cannot be even semi-Montel, let alone Montel.

Comment: Thanks @PedroLauridsenRibeirofor the precisions, I guess this strictness was included in the characterization as " finest topology satisfying [...] " or am I missing something?

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro In your third comment, closed subsets of $E_n$, say $F$, are closed in $E$ because, $\overline{F}^{\tau_E}=\overline{F}^{\tau_{E_n}}=F$  ? Perhaps I'm missing something, but how can we conclcude that  the unit ball is not compact in $C_0^k(\Omega)$?

Comment: @AymanMoussa Could you give some more details in the last statement of your answer? That is, how to justify if this unit ball is compact in $C_{0}^{k}(\Omega)$ then it is compact in $C_{K_n}^{k}(\Omega)$.

Comment: I rephrased the answer, I hope it's clearer now !

Comment: @Math A closed subset $F$ of $E_n$ is closed in $E$ because it's a closed subset in the relative topology (for $E$ induces the topology of $E_n$ for all $n$ since it's a strict (lc) inductive limit), hence it's the intersection of $E_n$ (which is closed in $E$) with a closed subset of $E$.

Comment: @AymanMoussa your definition of (lc) inductive limit topology is correct, but that by itself doesn't guarantee that $E$ induces the topology of $E_n$ for all $n$. There are plenty of examples of (lc) inductive limits which are not strict.